# Top n elements by column

Tags: python, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have this Spark dataframe:

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
   a |    g |    h |    p
   r |    i |    h |    l
   f |    j |    z |    d
   a |    j |    m |    l
   f |    g |    h |    q
   f |    z |    z |    a
 ...
```

I want to unpivot the columns and get an array of top n elements by occurence. For example with n=3:

```
columnName |   content
      col1 | [f, a, r]
      col2 | [g, j, i]
      col3 | [h, z, m]
      col4 | [l, a, d]
```

I managed to join the column names in a single column with this code:

```
columnNames = output_df.columns
output_df = output_df.withColumn("columns", F.array([F.lit(x) for x in columnNames]))
```

I think I could use the explode function but not sure it is the most efficient way of doing it.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: what does `top n elements` mean? By occurences?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken yes top n elements by occurence. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anyway except by computing manually all occurences, this is not really efficient, and I would be glad to hear for other methods.

But if you are not affraid about the performance issues, this would do the trick !

Be aware I am writing it in scala, I will try to translate it as pyspark, but as I have never done it before, that will be hard.

```
// Let's create a dataframe for reproductibility
val data = Seq(("a", "g", "h", "p"),
("r", "i", "h", "l"),
("f", "j", "z", "d"),
("a", "j", "m", "l"),
("f", "g", "h", "q"),
("f", "z", "z", "a"))

val df = data.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")

// Let's add a constant 1, with the groupby sum that will give us the occurencies !
val dfWithFuturOccurences = df.withColumn("futur_occurences", F.lit(1))

// Your n value
val n = 3

// Here goes the magic
df.columns // For each column
    .map(x => 
        (x, dfWithFuturOccurences
            .groupBy(x)
            .agg(sum("futur_occurences").alias("occurences")) // Count occurences here
            .orderBy(desc("occurences"))
            .select(x)
            .limit(n) // Select the top n elements
            .rdd.map(r => r(0).toString).collect().toSeq) //  Collect them and store them as a Seq of string
        )
    .toSeq
    .toDF("col", "top_elements")
```

In PySpark this is probably something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data = list(map(lambda x: 
            (x,
            [str(row[x]) for row in 
             dfWithFuturOccurences
            .groupBy(x)
            .agg(F.sum("futur_occurences").alias("occurences"))
            .orderBy(desc("occurences"))
            .select(x)
            .limit(n)
            .collect()]
            )
        , df.columns))
```

And then transform your data into a dataframe and that's done !

Output:

```
+----+------------+
| col|top_elements|
+----+------------+
|col1|   [f, a, r]|
|col2|   [g, j, z]|
|col3|   [h, z, m]|
|col4|   [l, p, d]|
+----+------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Shouldn't you work with `dfWithFuturOccurences` instead of `dfWithOccurences` at the beginning of the map? I've tried your code (pyspark) and got this error `in lambda TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`

Comment: @Maxbester You are right, I got lost in the shell ! Can you tell me which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The line of aggregation `.agg(sum("futur_occurences").alias("occurences"))`. I don't know if it is a cast issue with `F.lit(1)` or a data format problem in the dataframe.

Comment: @Maxbester, this should be working, I think the sum method was not from sparl sql functions but form the python built-in (I got the same error with a `sum('hello world')`)

Comment: @Maxbester, did that help you?

Comment: Well I replaced `sum` by `F.sum` and it seemed to be better but at the end it fails to execute the transformation. I have no explicit error though... Don't know what to do. Perhaps it is linked to the amount of data.

Comment: Oh, without error I might not be able to help you unfortunately